# Tomcat XSS filter

Tags: tomcat, xss

1. Hi I have this code for XSS filtering:

public class CrossSiteScriptingXSSRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

```
public CrossSiteScriptingXSSRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) throws IOException {
    super(servletRequest);
}

@Override
public String[] getParameterValues(String parameter) {
    String[] values = super.getParameterValues(parameter);

    if (values == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Stream<String> stream = Arrays.stream(values);

    if (values.length > 35) {
        stream = stream.parallel();
    }

    stream.forEach(value -> {
        XSSRemover.skipXSS(value);
    });

    return values;
}

@Override
public String getParameter(String parameter) {
    return XSSRemover.skipXSS(super.getParameter(parameter));
}

@Override
public String getHeader(String name) {
    return XSSRemover.skipXSS(super.getHeader(name));
}}
```

I want to ask if it's needed or it's possible to replace it with:

```
    <security:headers>
        <security:frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN"/>
        <security:xss-protection enabled="true"/>
        <security:cache-control/>
    </security:headers>
```

And then browser will handle it instead of filter? Thanks for answers :)

Comment: I'd argue that it's not needed - because you'd rather need to properly handle your input, rather than disallowing certain characters. I'd assume that your XSSRemover covers *some* cases, disallows otherwise perfectly legal parameters. And no browser-handling would be appropriate either IMHO. What is the underlying question? This sounds suspiciously like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: It's code from my job and I don't know why there is this filter - I didn't write it. But it's for every request and it's checking http header... What I am trying about it's speed up whole application and this filter is slowing down every request so I am thinking about to remove it or replace it but nobody knows why it's there and they are scared of security.. I just found it's from this page https://dzone.com/articles/stronger-anti-cross-site

Comment: The filter on that site is particularly bad. It allows very basic attacks like: `<vbscript:script>alert(1);</vbscript:script>` It's not really adding any protection.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [XSS Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet), you'll quickly realize that blacklisting known content will not secure a web application. Proper input handling is. That being said, you're stuck with the application that you're stuck with. And it's hard to say what will happen. I'd write some testcases and see if they're giving you the results that you expect (use the cheat sheet for gathering ideas on what to simulate).

That being said, putting the burden of protection onto the browser is only an additional element, and your server should handle (escape) its content correctly. Note: There's also an attack known as "stored XSS" - My long standing (and probably never executed on) plan is to write a book with the title `<script>alert("xss explained");</script>` - just to test the various shop implementations. It's a [perfectly valid title](https://xkcd.com/327/), and while a browser's xss-protection might not execute it, it also won't show the correct book title.

Also, the approach that your application has chosen only protects you from content coming through a browser. Anything that comes in through another frontend (API, integration, importer) might completely exploit the system. If that's an issue is left to you.